# Python will not read sys.argv

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, sys

```
    import sys

    print sys.argv[1]
```

hi,

this may seem very basic but I can't get Python to read in anything from the command line.
thats the code above and what I type is:

```
    myfile.py helloworld
```

and what i get back is:

```
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

It seemed to work once for me but won't work any more, and I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Python and it still doesnt work.

So my question is, am I doing anything wrong? or have I just broken Python?

Thanks for any help

Using:
Windows 7
Python 2.7.2

Comment: What happens when you just `print sys.argv`? And does it work, when calling the file via `python.exe myfile.py helloworld`?

Comment: ah, thanks for your responces, managed to get it working.
had a very silly mistake, didnt add python to the Path in system variables

Comment: For those having trouble passing arguments to a script in Windows without prepending it with a call to Python (e.g. `python foo.py a` works but `foo.py a` doesn't,) scroll past the first answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you are calling your python script the way you think you are?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "you did not give any arguments\n"
else:
    print sys.argv[1]
```

returns:

```
$ ./foo.py 
you did not give any arguments

$ ./foo.py hello_world
hello_world
$
```

Answer (score 23):

Start the registry editor (regedit). Set the *HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python26.exe\shell\open\command* key to:
`"C:\Python26\python26.exe" "%1" %*`

Source of this solution: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/12/14/problem-passing-arguments-to-python-scripts-on-windows/

Comment: wow, this registry omission bit us today, we were trying to balance a Python 2.7 Anaconda and 3.4 installation side by side. The 3.4 installer omitted that `%*` argument but we needed to set it for both the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\pythonxx.exe\shell\open\command` key as well as for the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\shell\open\command` key

Comment: This completely solved the problems I had passing command line args to Python 3.10.7 (which I installed using Scoop). I wonder how on Earth the person who originally found this solution, found it.