# Call python script with args in Windows

Tags: python, windows

I have written the simple script:

```
import sys
print("len(sys.argv): "+str(len(sys.argv)))    
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Wrong params. ex: 'touch.py file_name file_name2'")
    exit(1)    
for file in sys.argv[1:]:
    open(file, 'a')
```

Saved it, added at `PATH` and try to call from `CMD` like `touch.py fileName`, however my script get only 1 argument -- path to the script. So, how can I call python script from CMD with params? Does it problem only for Windows? What about linux?

Comment: I have idea to wrap python script into batch file, and pass args to batch

Comment: Is this question not helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically in Windows, you need to use `py -3` or `py -2` to tell the OS to run the file with `python`. Otherwise you're just executing the script in cmd with the default `exe`.

```
py -3 touch.py fileName
```

For other OS, use `python2` or `python3` in place of `py -3`

Comment: No, voltento's .py file association is broken (by the user or an IDE), as is commonly the case. If the user choice is `Python.File` and that ProgId is configured correctly to run `py.exe "%1" %*`, then you can run scripts in a shell directly or by double clicking them in Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `python`:

```
python touch.py fileName
```

Without specifying `python`, parameters are not passed.

---

To make the `cmd.exe` to pass argument (without specifying python), you need to modify registry. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24781215/2225682) or  [Eli Bendersky's website](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/12/14/problem-passing-arguments-to-python-scripts-on-windows/).

Comment: Eli's article is incomplete, to say the least. If Explorer 's user choice is currently an automatically created ProgId like `Applications\python*.exe` or `py_auto_file`, then either you or software running on your behalf has managed to break your Python installation. You should be using the `Python.File` progid, which among other things has the correct "open" command for py.exe (assuming Python 3 is installed using the py launcher) and also configures a drop handler using the shell extension library pyshellext.amd64.dll.